# On linear functionals with the trace property that aren't positive

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a C*-algebra and $\phi:A \to \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded linear functional satisfying $\phi(ab) = \phi(ba)$ (I call this the trace property). How far is $\phi$ from being a (positive) trace?

I'm aware that one can always find a partial isometry $v \in A^{**}$ such that $\psi(-) := \phi(- v)$ is positive. However, unless $v$ is central, $\psi$ may no longer have the trace property.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "how far"? I would call your $\phi$ a trace, and if $A$ is unital and has a trace in my sense then I believe $A$ should have a tracial state. (WLOG $\phi$ is a hermitian functional, then take the Hahn-Jordan decomposition and use uniqueness of that decomposition to get $u^*\cdot \phi_+\cdot u = \phi_+$ and $u^*\cdot\phi_-\cdot u=\phi_-$ for all unitary $u\in A$.)

Comment: You managed to predict what I wanted. I was concerned that $\phi$ need not be a linear combination of positive tracial states. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think this "trick" is obvious unless you see it somewhere else (in my case, I think it was the paper of Bunce and Paschke on quasi-expectations)